# Connection Refused when trying to connect to tcp socket (linux)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I'm working on ubunto linux version 14.04 (linux) using VM ware

I've created TCP socket in c++ under ubunto 14.04 (linux)
but when i try to use the "connect" method of the socket it fails and says
that the connection refused. I Tried to turn off the firewall in my windows (10) computer, but it didn't help at all.

your help would be highly appreciated!

```
TCPSocket::TCPSocket(string peerIp, int port) {
    // Open TCP socket
    this->connected_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (this->connected_sock < 0) {
        perror("Error opening channel");
    }

    // Set the peer address to connect to
    bzero(&this->peerAddr, sizeof(this->peerAddr));
    this->peerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    this->peerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(peerIp.c_str());
    this->peerAddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    // FAILED HERE
    if (connect(this->connected_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &this->peerAddr,
            sizeof(this->peerAddr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error establishing communications");
        throw "Error establishing communications";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the *exact* output from the `perror` call? And tell us what port you try to connect to? And there *is* some program listening at `peerIp` and at that port?

Comment: You have a networking problem between your VM and the host OS. Check the networking setup. Do you have something listening to what you're trying to connect to?

Comment: no, i saw the port is open it was "127.0.0.1" and port 13301
and i got "Connection Refused"  @jhauris

Comment: Usually if a network utility like netstat reports the IP as "127.0.0.1" then the socket is specifically bound to the local loopback address. It won't accept connections from any other machine. You mention Windows and Ubuntu, so I presume that you have at least two machines, although one or both might be virtual machines. In any case, you won't be able to make a connection to a socket that is specifically bound to 127.0.01 from any other machine, even a virtual machine running on the same physical host. It seems to me that the process that is listening, is not listening to the right things.

Comment: I resolved it, it was human error

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. `connection refused` means that somewhere along the path somebody sent a TCP reset packet back to the original source. Use a network traffic monitoring tool (e.g. tcpdump, wireshark) at notable points to track down where it's failing. A tcpdump example: `tcpdump -i <interface_name> -nnvvvXX host <destination_ip> and tcp port <destination_port>`

Comment: demo@ubuntu:~$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -nnvvvXX host 127.0.0.1 and tcp port 13301
[sudo] password for demo: 
tcpdump: WARNING: eth0: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
thats what i got..

Comment: I am using my crystal ball here, but it looks like a networking issue. Make sure your VM has networking enabled either as NAT or bridge. Make sure your VM gets an IP address assigned by your DHCP server. If you don't have one, assign it statically. `127.0.0.1` is localhost, it is not publicly routable. Unless the service you are connecting to lives on the same VM, you need to use the public IP of that machine.

Comment: Hi tom. The vm is not connected to the network. How can i define tge dhcp to local host?

Comment: How does you host operating system (assuming Windows) get an IP address? Regardless, I still don't see the full picture here. Which machine (IP address) does the service you are connecting to live on? If it's on the same box, `peerIp` can be `127.0.0.1`, if not, then it *must* be a publicly routable IP address. Footnote: for help with networking on Ubuntu visit https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

So i solved the issue!

I was dumb...

the soultion is in the calling => i called different ports.

server listens to port 13301
and the clients needs to connect to the same port,
only then the server accept the client and opens new socket with him..

Thanks so much for you kind help !